# How to make Stylus to see the variable that has been initialized in other scope?

Tags: stylus

In SASS:

```
.DocumentationArticle

  $DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector: null

  &-Heading
    &__TopLevel
      $DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector: &
    &__Section
      @debug($DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector) // OK: ".DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel"
```

In Stylus, in variable value has been changed, this change visible only in scope where it has been changed:

```
.DocumentationArticle

  DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector = null

  &-Heading
    &__TopLevel
      DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector = selector()
    &__Section
      warn(DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector) // null!
```

How to make `DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector` new value visible in `&__Section` scope?

[Fiddle](https://stylus-lang.com/try.html#?code=.DocumentationArticle%0A%0A%20%20DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector%20%3D%20null%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%26-Heading%0A%20%20%20%20%26__TopLevel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector%20%3D%20selector()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector%0A%20%20%20%20%26__SecondLever%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20content%3A%20DocumentationArticle-Heading__TopLevel--Selector)